# JS - Breaking lines while parsing is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with a small stuff here, I'm trying to simply break the line using a JQuery API (From Plug.DJ), but it's not parsing my `\n` nor `<br>`. What should I do?

Things I tested:

```
API.chatLog("Line01\n" + "Line02"); // Will idsplay "Line01Line02"

API.chatLog("Line01" + '<br>' + "Line02"); // Will display "Line01<br>Line02"
```

What should I try?

Comment: have you tried `\n\r`?

Comment: Yes, it's parsing it like if it wasn't there.

Comment: Where is that plugin "parsing" your string? Please link its code or documentation, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, the Front-End-API documentation is here ( very poor ):
[link](http://support.plug.dj/hc/en-us/sections/200353347-Front-End-API?flash_digest=b036dc4734ec5f0c6e0295286fcd50ee08098210)
I'm using the API.chatLog function.

Comment: This is basically what is says: http://i.imgur.com/jUvx2J8.png ( So you don't need to log-in)

Comment: Hm. Nothing mentions that it supports linebreaks. I feel like a chat API might try to support things like colors, smilies, and links, so maybe it really does expect full HTML, and expects you to write <br/>? If you see documentation otherwise, link that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered it. To do, simply use the PhP Append method.

Like: $('#chat-messages').append("Line1
Line2
");